# ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64'). for my knn model

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

```
df1_fit=pd.DataFrame(scaled_features,columns=df1.columns[:-1])
df1_fit.head()

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X_train, X_test, y_train, 
y_test=train_test_split(scaled_features,df1['Sales'],test_size=0.30)

from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier

knn=KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=5)
knn.fit(X_train,y_train)
```

then i run it but it shows me, `ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64')`

how i can solve it?

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have no `NaN` values:

```
df1 = df1.dropna()
```